# Laravel 403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED. when email verifying

Tags: php, laravel

I looked up in `Laravel/8.x` docs and setup routes for email verification. Here are the routes:

```
Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
    return view('auth.verify-email');
})->middleware('auth')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();

    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::post('/email/verification-notification', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('message', 'Verification link sent!');
})->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('verification.send');
```

When i click on this `<a href="{{ route('verification.verify', ['id' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::id(), 'hash' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->password]) }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Verify email</a>` It gives me this error: `403 INVALID SIGNATURE`.

EDIT:

I switched to `signedRoute` in my `a` tag and now i get `403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.`.

Here is mechanism that leads to `verification.verify` route:

```
@if (Route::has('login'))
        <div class="hidden fixed top-0 right-0 px-6 py-4 sm:block">
            @auth
            <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Home</a>
            <a href="{{ URL::signedRoute('verification.verify', [
                            'id' =>Auth::id(),
                            'hash' => Auth::user()->password,
                        ])}}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Verify email</a>
            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Logout</a>
            @else
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Login</a>
            @if (Route::has('register'))
            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Register</a>
            @endif
            @endauth
        </div>
        @endif
```

In `EmailVerificationRequest` i've changed nothing:

under `vendor\Laravel\Framework\src\Illuminate\Founndation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest`

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EmailVerificationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('id'),
                          (string) $this->user()->getKey())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('hash'),
                          sha1($this->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Fulfill the email verification request.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function fulfill()
    {
        if (! $this->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            $this->user()->markEmailAsVerified();

            event(new Verified($this->user()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Comment: share the full request and response to give the question more context please

Comment: @DavidDiez edited question. I used Laravel's `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest` `Request`. The response is simply  `403 |THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `URL::signedRoute` to generate signed urls, not the `route` helper.

```php
URL::signedRoute('verification.verify', [
    'id' => Auth::id(),
    'hash' => Auth::user()->password,
]);
```

You can read here for more information about signed urls: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls

---

You are receiving a 403 because you are not passing the parameters that the framework is expecting.

```php
URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'verification.verify',
    Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
    [
        'id' => Auth::user()->getKey(),
        'hash' => sha1(Auth::user()->getEmailForVerification()),
    ]
);
```

Comment: Now it gives me `403
THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.` error. Should i make another question?

Comment: @YarkinBey 403 is returned from the request's authorize method. You can check if the authorize method in `EmailVerificationRequest` returns `true`.

Comment: I mean there is something there but the one thing got my attention is            `sha1($this->user()->getEmailForVerification())))` line. I don't know what that is. Is it user password or something else?

Comment: @YarkinBey The `getEmailForVerification` returns the email of the user using `sha1`, not the password. Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is very old, but in case anyone is stuck here same me.
I'm using Laravel 8 too and using the laravel/ui as my web auth scaffold.
I searched the internet some says it about the Nginx's rewrite and some say it about the TrustProxies, but actually the issue for me is the verify link inside the email is:

```
https://test.com/email/verify/2?expires=1644740715&hash=b0f4f567f00280291e508b44f882f6efd494eb32&signature=2f998b6895ef7721b2905fbb432872b6181672de5aaf6e7f4be443d8184f6fc2
```

but the VerifiesEmails trait's verify function is

```
        if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user()->getKey())) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($request->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }
```

Just change the $request->route('hash') to $request->get('hash') my problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

your answer code route change

email/verify/{id}/{hash}

```
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@verify')>name('verification.verify');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).